# R filter based on multiple keys in data.table with one key not limited

Tags: r, data.table

Take the built-in mtcars dataset.

```
DT <- data.table(mtcars)
setkey(DT, am, gear, carb)
```

Following the vignette, I know that if I want to have filtering that corresponds to am == 1 & gear == 4 & carb == 4, I can write:

```
DT[.(1,4,4)]
```

however,if I don't care at some moment what the value gear is, what should I do?

```
DT[.(1,anyvalue,4)]
```

FYI, I need a solution **not** listing every vallue,if you have millions of different value, you can't list them all.

Comment: should have a dupe somewhere. you can do `DT[,.(1, unique(gear), 4)]`

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237820/r-data-table-by-group-by-order-of-keys-and-missing-keys)

Comment: What is the application? You could do `DT[.(1, 4), on = .(am, carb)]`, but I guess that's not what you're after.

Comment: @sindri_baldur this structure is interesting. what is this structure for? join?or another way to match key? I mean the one like you mentioned like      DT[.(value1,value2),on = .(a,b)]

Comment: @cloudscomputes this is join syntax but can also be used just for filtering.