# R: subsetting issue with some datatables when using column value/position for subsetting

Tags: r, data.table, subset

With some data.table i am facing subsetting issue.

for example if i need 4th,8th and 9th column of a particular data table "y" i used below code, but as a result it is creating vector of 4,8,9 instead of getting 4th,8th and 9th columns

```
y<-data.table(rnorm(100),pnorm(100),rnorm(100),pnorm(100),rnorm(100),pnorm(100),rnorm(100),pnorm(100),rnorm(100),pnorm(100))
req<-y[,c(4,8,9)]
req
```

for the above code result is an vector output of 4,8,9

```
# [1] 4 8 9
```

for only some data table i am facing this issue.Can anyone please resolve this ?

Comment: Are you mixing up data.frames and data.tables?  This link may help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487269/subsetting-in-data-table if you do mean data.tables.

Comment: Please [read the vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
req<-y[,c(4,8,9),with=FALSE]
```

I think it will give you what you want

Comment: thanks. Is there any default setting to make with=FALSE.   As i am facing problem with only some data tables.

Comment: No I dont think you can set the with to false by default. This is the way the way the data table was designed. Setting it to false allows you to use the data table as a data frame. Perhaps you want to try 
y <- data.frame(rnorm(100)... ) where you do not need to specify the with=False. You can read this faq post http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf about the data table, it is very useful!

Comment: @George91 this FAQ is quite outdated, use this link instead: https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html

Answer (score 0):

At least two options here:

```
# using column name
y[ , .(V4,V8,V9)]

# using column position
y[, c(4,8,9), with = FALSE]
```